# how to make my chrome extension works in all browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have developed an extension for printing my html page and its work perfectly in chrome browser now i want to make some changes that will to run my extension in all browsers like Firefox, opera etc

So can anyone tell me what kind of changes i have to do in my extension code

i have made the following change but it not work

```
window.browser = (function () {
    return window.msBrowser ||
        window.browser ||
        window.chrome;
})();
```

if anyone can help i glad to him please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: AFAIK, every browser have their own way of implementing extensions. You can check this [link](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/install-chrome-extensions-on-firefox) on how to install Chrome extensions on Firefox browser. Also, this [tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-a-cross-browser-extension-using-javascript-and-browser-apis-355c001cebba) covers how to create a web extension that works across multiple browsers. It will show you how to structure a project and write JavaScript code to interact with the browser’s tabs, depending on which browser is being used.

Comment: thank you for your response i found something that helps me

Comment: i had refer https://github.com/EmailThis/extension-boilerplate/tree/master/src/scripts/utils ,   ext.js for working in multiple browser.